# I am having the error CS1513, even though I have the right amount of brackets. (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(Solved) I recently started Unity to code, and am making a single player shooter. It is giving me the error CS1513, even though I believe I have all of the ending brackets that I need. The exact error message is:

> Assets\PlayerShoot.cs(32,36): error CS1513: } expected

Even if I delete the else statement or change the variables to private, it still shows the error. Here is the code to look through, although be advised that the line numbers are not part of the code:

```
29 void Update () 
30    {
31        fireRate -= Time.deltaTime;
32        if (equipped == "raygun") {
33            //This is the error ^
34        
35        public float damage = 25f;
36        public float range = 100f;
37        fireRate -= 0.8;
38             
39             if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && fireRate <= 0) {
40            Shoot ();
41        }
42        } else {
43            
44            public float damage = 20f;
45            public float range = 100f;
46            fireRate -= 0.15;
47
48            if (Input.GetButtonHold("Fire1") && fireRate <= 0) {
49                Shoot ();
50            }
51        }
52    }
```

Comment: Your code's too weirdly formatted to look through, but... Here's a few pointers. 1) if you are using Visual Studio, you can auto-format your code (in the Edit->Advanced menu or just `<ctrl>+A` then `<ctrl>+K` & `<ctrl>+F`). You can also place your cursor on a bracket in your code and then press `<ctrl>+]`.  That will jump to the matching bracket (works with parens, brackets and curly brackets). and as @KenWhite points out, when talking about an error, include the code, the full text (if in a foreign language include the full text and a translation) and an indicator of the line#

Comment: Sometimes an stray character in one part of the file can cause an error in a different part of the file because of the way the syntax tree is parsed. To confirm that the problem is actually within your `Update()` method, try removing all of its code (so it is just an empty method) and see if the project compiles. If it does, put the code back into the method, a little at a time, until it breaks.

Comment: The error occurs on line 32, which does not contain an error. This leads me to believe the issue is in the code before what you've included here, as your code starts on line 29. Please [edit] to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. An MRE means code that can be copied and pasted from your question into a code editor and compiled to produce the exact same error. We can't help with code we can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>    public float damage = 25f;
>    public float range = 100f;
> ```

Did you intend for `damage` and `range` to be local variables?

The `public` keyword isn't allowed on a local variable, so the C# compiler assumes that you meant for those lines to be outside your function, which is equivalent to assuming you meant to have more closing braces to end the function.

Comment: Thanks for this. The error has been fixed, but now another error pops up. Because the variables are no longer public, they can not be used in the `Shoot ()` command, specifically "The variable 'damage' is assigned but its value is never used' and the same thing with range. Is there a way to call the variable into the shoot command?

Comment: @Elanigor: That would be a new issue, which belongs in a new question. Your question here has been answered.

Comment: Move the two variable up outside your function, into class scope rather than function scope.  Put the `public` back on them.  Read up on variables and  _Scope_